# Kendo grid multiple columns from single field

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Hi this is my first question here and hopefully it will be useful for other people as well. I have been researching for about 3 days now but haven't found anything that fulfills my requirement.

What I am trying to do looks very simple but I haven't seen a way to do it, my scenario is much more complicated than this but I will try to keep this as simple as possible.

Currently I have a list of names which is pretty large and I'm showing that in a kendo grid, it looks like this:

[image]

Since this grid will always have just 1 column (Names) I want to show 4-5 columns all from the field Names to use all the space of the page and also to show more information at once, I want it to look more or less like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    $("#gridNames").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({

            pageSize: 10,
            data: data

        }),
        pageable: true,
        pageSize: 10,
        columns: [
            { field: "Name", title: "Name" },
            { field: "Name", title: "Name" }]
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, let me know if I didn't explain myself.

Comment: what do you want to display in the additional columns? why do you want to use the same field for multiple columns? should each column display a different value, and if so, where does it come from? your pictures don't explain much tbh

Comment: Ya sorry I wasn't clear, what I want to do is.. let's say I have a dataset of 50 names, what I would want to do is show them all in 5 columns with 10 names in each column, if I had 100 names I would want 2 pages showing 50 names in each page, please tell me if I'm not clear.. Thanks!

Comment: It could be done in a grid by having 5 properties in your viewmodel, and splitting the list up in your controller. Though it seems a bit overkill. Have you tried using a [listview](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/listview/index.html) instead? It is better suited at showing a 'page' of info over multiple columns and rows.